# A fast photo browser for Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, images, photos, performance

What is the fastest photo browser for Linux?

I'm talking about 8 megapixel JPG photos, and some TIFF panoramas (some are about 50MB big). I don't need much functionality – simple browsing with some zoom in/out would do.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Which graphical environment? Gnome, KDE? Does it matter?

Comment: I use GNOME, but apps from KDE are also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend GNOME's default image viewer (if you're using GNOME as desktop manager), since it's pretty lightweight and thus faster. Anyway the loading time of images is directly related to your processing power (CPU/RAM/HDD speed)

Answer (score 1):

Picasa on linux is rather fast, but in terms of resources it is *not* light (has some other drawbacks; for example standard workflow will require you to import the images into the library before viewing them)

Answer (score 0):

[qiv](http://www.klografx.net/qiv/) is a good one to try.  [Imagemagick display](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/display.html) can do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [gwenview](http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/). it's simple and was always fast enough for me.
More important than the viewer will be the read performance of the storage device.

[image]